# Error integrating Twitter via Fabric

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm getting the following error when trying to integrate Twitter via the Fabric installation (cocoapods):

`Value of type 'module<Twitter>' does not conform to expected element type 'AnyObject'`

[image: Error screenshot]

Version of Xcode: 7.1
I imported the `Twitter` module, of course, cleaned the project and cleaned Derived Data as well.

Comment: Did you followed the steps from the getting started guide?

Comment: Replace Twitter.self to Fabric.with([Twitter.sharedInstance()])

Comment: @Cristik: yes. Kirit Modi: I already tried that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to `import TwitterKit`, and not `import Twitter` (as in Fabric's setup instructions)

The same issue is when installing Crashlytics. They are instructing to import Fabric and Crashlytics module, but not TwitterKit module, and at the same time they are initializing Fabric with Twitter as well.

Comment: Mike from Fabric and Crashlytics here. Can you let me know where you saw this sample code so that I can correct it?